# Mysql AND WHERE selection

Tags: php, mysql

i have te make a slection but cannot get it to work with the WHERE LIKE function. What is wrong with the line below?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE soort='nieuws' AND gamenaam='$spelnaam' AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%' AND ORDER BY id DESC");
```

It worked until i added

```
AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%'
```

The platform column contains cells with multiple values that come from a selection box form. So it writes, wiiu, ps4, xbox360, pc etc....Must be simple but i tried like a million times...

Comment: Do those cells match the rest of the conditions in the `where` clause?  The most likely reason for not returning anything is that there are no matches in the data.

Comment: Remove AND before ORDER BY

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the `AND` before `ORDER BY`

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE soort='nieuws' AND gamenaam='$spelnaam' AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%' AND ORDER BY id DESC");
```

should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE soort='nieuws' AND gamenaam='$spelnaam' AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an extra `AND`, it should be:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE soort='nieuws' AND gamenaam='$spelnaam' AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 2):

please don't use mysql_* as it's deprecated, use mysqli_ or PDO instead. 
ref to http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

and change your query to

```
SELECT * FROM games 
WHERE soort='nieuws' 
AND gamenaam='$spelnaam' 
AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%' 
ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE soort='nieuws' AND gamenaam='$spelnaam' AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

You hav extra 'AND' at the end

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM games
WHERE soort = 'nieuws'
AND gamenaam = '$spelnaam'
AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%'
ORDER BY id DESC
```

There should not be an `AND` before an `ORDER BY` statement.

**Also**, I feel the obligatory urge to ask that you look into using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` functions, as `mysql` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM games WHERE soort='nieuws' AND gamenaam='$spelnaam' AND platform LIKE '%wiiu%' ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should not put comma separated values in a field. You actually provided a good example of why not by saying you've got console names in there. What if you're looking for something related to the original Wii? You'd have something like `WHERE soort LIKE "%wii%"`, right? Well, this would also return all WiiU related items, because "WiiU" is also LIKE "%wii%".

The proper way to do this involves making and joining a link table.